How to set a Google Tag Manager (GTM) trigger for a toast that appears in multiple pages?
I'd like to set a GTM trigger for a specific toast that appears after a form submission in multiple pages on my website, but I'm having a hard time :(
My original idea was to use to toast class for that, since it is always the same, but I don't know how to set a variable for when this class appears in the page.
Any suggestion?
GTM has a variable for click class, but not for when the page just displays a class, that is why I considered creating a custom variable for that.

The best practice here is to ask whoever is responsible for maintaining that part of the site to push a dataLayer object whenever the toast appears.
Otherwise, you don't need a variable. You need a trigger. The element visibility trigger. It takes a CSS selector, so you'd use that class in there. This trigger's implementation, however, is based on simple polling, so it's generally not advised to use it and when you do, it's best to limit it to only run on the specific pages you need it.

As BNazaruk mentioned, you can use the Element Visibility trigger for this case. Here’s how:
1.  Set the trigger to fire on All Visibility Events: This allows you to initially capture any appearance of the toast class across the site. Make sure to check **Observe DOM changes** so that the trigger detects the toast even if it’s dynamically added after page load.
2.  Use GTM Preview Mode: Once the trigger is set, go into Preview Mode and observe what gets recorded when the specific toast is displayed. Pay close attention to variables such as the class or other DOM elements associated with the toast.
3.  Narrow the trigger: After observing the specific variables associated with the toast in Preview Mode, refine your trigger by switching from **All Visibility Events** to **Some Visibility Events**. This will allow you to target only the specific instance when the toast appears by applying the observed variables.

